# xcode: ios dynamic frameworks show "Entitlements 0" when submitting

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

I've searched for hours but cannot find an answer. I have a xcode project with Cocoapods 0.39. in my Podfile i use !use_frameworks to enable a external Swift library in my Objective-C project.

But when i validate (or submit) with xcode, i get the codesigning dialog box. Normally only my app is shown but now it also shows the dynamic framework (cocoapods dependency). I think this is because of the !use_frameworks option.

The screenshot shows the dialog:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Fall.png)

I can upload my binary to testflight and it will get processed but is this something i need to worry about? Is likely that apple will reject my app  because of this?

Comment: Dont worry about Rejection... Apple will not reject it. All the Cocoapods frameworks get compiled externally.. so apple will not reject

Comment: I'm not positive that's true.  I just started experiencing this when producing an enterprise build and the app won't launch at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to worry about it, cocoapods are usually shown in codesigning dialog box, every cocoapod dependency that you will use will be shown there, there will be no issue and Apple will also not reject cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

If you can upload your binary, I guess your minimum deployment target is iOS 8.0 or above, also in your Swift source code, you must

```
import AXRatingView
```

If your App's minimum deployment target is iOS 7, you can do this in the Podfile

```
#use_frameworks!
```

and comment

```
//import AXRatingView
```

then in your ...Bridging-Header.h

```
#import <AXRatingView/AXRatingView.h>
```

My App's minimum deployment target is iOS 7.0, ready for sale now.

Comment: My app Deployment Target 10.0 and my SDK target deployment target 8.0..... so is it workable or not ?

Comment: If your App's deployment target is above 8.0, you can simply use 'use_frameworks!' in Podfile, and then 'import SDKNAME' in Swift file.